# Elasticsearch Index Template Refresh

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using Java API for `Elasticsearch 5.2.2` and have seen that creation of `Index Templates` intermittently takes time to get created.
Hence, when I create an index template and check if it got created successfully, sometimes it returns template size as 0.

```
GetIndexTemplatesResponse response = client.admin().indices().prepareGetTemplates(TEMPLATE_NAME).execute().actionGet();
System.out.println(response.getIndexTemplates().size()); // returns 0
```

My question is, (to overcome this) is there a refresh of all the index templates?
Something similar to all indices refresh? (Java equivalent):

```
esClient.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check the `PutIndexTemplateResponse`, there is an option to check if the action was acknowledged. If it was the template has been added successfully.